# Fullcalendar select date callback

Tags: events, select, fullcalendar

I have a strange problem with fullcalendar (v 3.4.0) that I can't understand.
In "month" view when I select more days, it returns a outlandish date.

For example, on select days from 20-08-2017 to 24-08-2017 the callback for start is: `1503187200000`, and for end is `1503619200000`.
I create a new date object for both and the `getHours()` method return me "**2**".

**But**
if I select days from 14-12-2017 to 16-12-2017 now hours is "**1**".

At first I think that it's a timezone problem, so in the option I set `timezone: false`, but this don't work!
This is my code:

```
var element = $("#calendario");

element.fullCalendar({
    theme: true,
    selectable: true,
    editable: true,
    defaultTimedEventDuration: "01:00:00",
    timezone: false,
    eventLimit: true,
    header: {
        left: '',
        center: 'prev title next',
        right: ''
    },
    select: function (start, end, jsEvent, view) {
        alert(start + "\n" + end);
        ShowAddEvent(start, end, view);
        element.fullCalendar('unselect');
    },
    eventClick: function (event, jsEvent, view) {
        var idEvento = event.id;
        EventDetails(idEvento);
    }
});
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: why do you create a new Date object for them? `start` and `end` are already momentJS objects. `start.hours();` will get you the hours immediately. The timestamp you're seeing is just the default printout momentJS gives if you try to alert/log the moment object directly. Anyway, since you're only selecting days (in the month view, this is all that it's possible to do), then the time component surely isn't relevant - you can just ignore it and use the date part?

Comment: Thanks for the help!